# Divide a dataframe to two DF by value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**My frame:**

```
name    rs      number
11      5566     64882
41      534326   5345
11      5566     3312
44      2341     5553
1       6223     2333
```

It has 700k+ rows.

```
df.rs.value_counts() = 

5566 2
534326 1
2341 1
6223 1
```

I need to divine that frame to 2 other smaller frames by value_counts.
I mean: in `UniqueDF` should be only rows without rs repetition:

```
    name    rs      number
    41      534326   5345
    44      2341     5553
    1       6223     2333
```

And in `DuplicatedDF` should be only repetition (all duplicated rows, coz rs could be same, but another cols have different value):

```
name    rs      number
11      5566     64882
11      5566     3312
```

I tried something like this:

```
Duplicate_rs_df = df.drop(df.index[np.where(df.rs.value_counts() <1)])

unique1 = df.drop(df.index[np.where(df.rs.value_counts() >1)])
```

But when I check that dfs by couts_values still both have a repetitions. 
What is wrong in my code and how can I do that in better way?

Comment: is the expected df for UniqueDf correct? I can still see `rs` with repetition

Comment: you can use drop duplicates on rs

Comment: @anky_91 sorry, edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)  with `keep=False`:

Given `df`:

```
   name      rs  number
0    11    5566   64882
1    41  534326    5345
2    11    5566    3312
3    44    2341    5553
4     1    6223    2333
```

Using `drop_duplicates`:

```
uniq_df = df.drop_duplicates('rs', False)
print(uniq_df)

   name      rs  number
1    41  534326    5345
3    44    2341    5553
4     1    6223    2333
```

And using `duplicated`:

```
dup_df = df[df.duplicated('rs', False)]
print(dup_df)

   name    rs  number
0    11  5566   64882
2    11  5566    3312
```

---

Or even simpler, use `df.duplicated('rs', False)` only:

```
ind = df.duplicated('rs', False)
print(df[~ind])

   name      rs  number
1    41  534326    5345
3    44    2341    5553
4     1    6223    2333

print(df[ind])
   name    rs  number
0    11  5566   64882
2    11  5566    3312
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep both dfs in a dict:

```
d={f'df_{i}':g for i,g in df.groupby(
     np.where(df.rs.duplicated(keep=False),'duplicated','Unique'))}

print(d['df_Unique'])
```

---

```
   name      rs  number
1    41  534326    5345
3    44    2341    5553
4     1    6223    2333
```

---

```
print(d['df_duplicated'])

   name    rs  number
0    11  5566   64882
2    11  5566    3312
```